# Remove unused images

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a lot of word documents which contain just a few lines of text but are quite big because they contain in *media* folder a lot of images which aren't used in the document.

These documents were created from some other documents automatically (original huge document was splitted to a lot of smaller ones) but media folder is the same for all of them.

Is it possible through some command-line tool or API to "rebuild" these word files and let it remove all images which aren't actually used in the document?

Thanks

Sample document:
[image]

docx content:
...dokumentace>dir /s
                ...
                ...

```
    Directory of ...dokumentace

    02.08.2016  11:20    <DIR>          .
    02.08.2016  11:20    <DIR>          ..
    16.05.2016  09:38        36 898 802 1459401316308.docx
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          docProps
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          word
    16.05.2016  09:29             2 050 [Content_Types].xml
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          _rels
    2 File(s)     36 900 852 bytes

    Directory of ...dokumentace\docProps

    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          .
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          ..
    16.05.2016  09:29             1 193 app.xml
    16.05.2016  09:29               806 core.xml
    2 File(s)          1 999 bytes

    Directory of ...dokumentace\word

    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          .
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          ..
    16.05.2016  09:29            10 393 document.xml
    16.05.2016  09:29             1 497 endnotes.xml
    16.05.2016  09:29             3 131 fontTable.xml
    16.05.2016  09:29             2 308 footer1.xml
    16.05.2016  09:29             1 503 footnotes.xml
    16.05.2016  09:29             6 411 header1.xml
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          media
    16.05.2016  09:29            23 220 numbering.xml
    16.05.2016  09:29             6 596 settings.xml
    16.05.2016  09:29            34 704 styles.xml
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          theme
    16.05.2016  09:29             1 736 webSettings.xml
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          _rels
    10 File(s)         91 499 bytes

    Directory of ...dokumentace\word\media

    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          .
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          ..
    16.05.2016  09:29           653 660 image1.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 545 472 image10.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 467 037 image11.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 386 511 image12.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         2 016 615 image13.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         2 006 753 image14.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 997 685 image15.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 999 302 image16.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29           200 378 image17.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29           199 976 image18.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29        24 287 364 image19.emf
    16.05.2016  09:29           655 741 image2.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29            24 621 image20.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29            25 604 image21.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 691 115 image22.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 619 966 image23.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 620 689 image24.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29           148 374 image25.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         2 137 482 image26.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29            26 316 image27.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29            25 083 image28.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29            31 111 image29.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29           478 211 image3.png
    16.05.2016  09:29            22 263 image30.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29            44 972 image31.png
    16.05.2016  09:29            44 305 image32.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29             8 171 image33.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29           502 250 image4.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29           640 875 image5.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29           693 125 image6.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 335 739 image7.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 392 171 image8.jpeg
    16.05.2016  09:29         1 276 885 image9.jpeg
    33 File(s)     52 205 822 bytes

    Directory of ...dokumentace\word\theme

    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          .
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          ..
    16.05.2016  09:29             6 795 theme1.xml
    1 File(s)          6 795 bytes

    Directory of ...dokumentace\word\_rels

    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          .
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          ..
    16.05.2016  09:29             6 057 document.xml.rels
    16.05.2016  09:29               461 header1.xml.rels
    2 File(s)          6 518 bytes

    Directory of ...dokumentace\_rels

    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          .
    02.08.2016  11:10    <DIR>          ..
    16.05.2016  09:29               580 .rels
    1 File(s)            580 bytes

    Total Files Listed:
            51 File(s)     89 214 065 bytes
```

Comment: did you try programmatically looping over these files and searching for thiese media folders, and removing them ?

Comment: Images are "used" in documents.xml.rel which looks like some kind of resource definitions but more importantly in some documents there are actually used. So I would break those. If I don't find any better solution I will do fulltext search over .xml files and remove images which aren't in them.